# Why KeyboardAvoidingView is ignoring behavior prop as Stack Screen?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm currently developing a mobile application for iOS and Android using Expo version 50.0.6, React Native version 0.73.4 and Expo Router version 3.4.7.

Unfortunately, I've encountered unexpected behavior today and I'm still struggling to understand its root cause. Essentially, I noticed that when a screen within a Stack has a parent component of type KeyboardAvoidingView, the `behavior` prop is ignored, resulting in the keyboard covering elements on the screen.

Here's how my screen and router configurations are set up:

```js
// src/app/_layout.tsx

export default function Layout() {
 ...

      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
          <Slot />
        </View>
      )

}
```

```js
// src/app/(auth)/_layout.tsx

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Stack
      screenOptions={{
        headerShadowVisible: false,
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#f9fafb" },
        contentStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#f9fafb" ,
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
          paddingVertical: 16,
        },
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

```js
// src/app/(auth)/index.tsx

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "space-between" }}
      behavior={Platform.select({ ios: "padding", android: "height" })}
    >
      ...
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}
```

As mentioned, this issue particularly occurs on any screen where the parent component is a KeyboardAvoidingView within a Stack. KeyboardAvoidingView behavior prop issue persisting on iOS as you can see below.

[image]
[image]

Any insights into why the behavior prop of KeyboardAvoidingView might be ignored within a Stack would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!